# Complex entire functions without taking values on a segment are constant!

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, maximum-principle

Let $a,b$ be two distinct complex numbers and $f$ be an entire complex function, i.e. a complex function which is analytic on the whole complex plane, and
$$R(f)\subset\mathbb C-\{\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b|
\lambda\in[0,1]\}$$
Then $f$ is a constant function!

---

Comments:
With taking $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-a}{b-a}$ we may suppose that the segment is $[0,1]$.
Obviously we can't use Picard's theorem!

Comment: You said we can't use Little Picard's theorem, why?

Comment: Because in that case, the solution gets obvious...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have already reduced it to the case where $g(z)$ misses $[0,1]$, consider $1/g(z) - 1$ which is now entire and misses the non-negative real line.

Take its square root (why can you do that?) it is an entire function missing the lower half plane.

Find a fractional linear transformation mapping the upper half plane to the inside of the unit disc.

Now you have an entire function that is bounded.

Apply Liouville.

Comment: In the first paragraph you should take $1-\frac1{g(z)}$. And why it's square root misses lower half plane??!!

Comment: @k1.M I don't think so. $1/g(z)$ misses $[1,\infty)$. So I meant exactly what I wrote. Though with judicious choices of the square root function either one will work.

Comment: @k1.M: to your second question, the range of $1/g(z) - 1$ has argument $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$, so its square root has argument $\theta\in (0,\pi)$.

Comment: That was better to take $1-\frac1{g(z)}$ because in this case you can take square root in principal branch!

Comment: We can use these two facts to $g$ that image of a non-constant entire function is dense and connected.