# Non-constant entire function without taking any real values

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Does there exist a non-constant entire function $f$ such that $f(\mathbb{C})\subseteq \mathbb{C}\smallsetminus \mathbb{R}?$

Can we show that such a function doesn't exist by combining the two facts that image of a non-constant entire function is dense and connected? Or is there any other way also? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1221378/42969, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2562196/42969